# scroll bar is moving to top when button click event is fires. I want to stop scroll bar movement at particular positon

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I'm displaying data in a table from database by button click. I have multiple buttons and multiple tables. I want to move scroll bar to particular div based on button click. every time scroll bar is moving to top when i click any button.
This is the code i'm using to move scroll bar at particular position.

```
<input type="submit"  name="search"  id ="search" onclick="myFunctionq();" value="Display" /> 
<script>
function myFunctionq(){
    var divLoc = $('#div1').offset();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divLoc.top},"slow");
    };
</script>
```

This is not working to me.

If I write same code in  $(document).ready(function()) it is working and every time scroll bar is moving.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var divLoc = $('#div1').offset();
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divLoc.top}, "slow");

  });
</script>
```

I want to move scroll position to div based on button click events.

Comment: add return false to cancel default event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click to button, it call you function and call event submit and your page is refresh. you need add to onclick return false or e.preventDefault, to disabled default event

```
<input type="submit"  name="search"  id ="search" onclick="return myFunctionq();" value="Display" /> 
<script>
function myFunctionq(){
    var divLoc = $('#div1').offset();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divLoc.top},"slow");
    return false
    };
</script>
<?php if isset($_POST['search']):?> <script>myFunctionq()</script> <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Actually I'm displaying data in a table from database by button click. If I'm using e.prevent.Default data is not displaying in table. I tried using return false but still scroll bar is moving to top.

Comment: it means, that you need send form data.
Then you need call function after refresh page.
if it post query, you can do
<?php if isset($_POST['search']):?>
<script>myFunctionq()</script>
<?php endif;?>
you can remove call the function from button event

Comment: Its working now after adding   <?php if isset($_POST['search']):?> <script>myFunctionq()</script> <?php endif;?> Thank you so much...